# Diagnose slow JDBC select statements against SQL Server running in a Hyper-V VM

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, hyper-v

We have just built a new Hyper-V virtual machine to host a Java application and Microsoft SQL Server. We've run into extremely slow responses from the database when running SQL select queries from a Java JDBC application. The same queries execute quickly when run from SQL Server Management Studio.

We've run the same Java applications and SQL Server databases on bare metal and in VMware virtual machines without any performance issues.

Our questions:

- Have other developers seen similar performance issues in a Hyper-V virtual machine?
- How can we diagnose what is causing the performance bottleneck for the JDBC applications?

Example query:

```
select * from view1 where app_id in (
    select app_id from app_table where app_id % 1000 = 0)
order by app_id
```

Response times:

- SQL Server: 45k rows in 9 to 36 seconds, depending on RAM, CPUs, etc
- Java application: over 4 hours

Hyper-V virtual machine

- Windows Server 2019 host
- Hyper-V Configuration 9, Generation 2

The app_table table has just two columns.

```
create table app_table (
  app_id [numeric](18,0) not null,
  col_2 [varchar] (75)
)
```

The app_view view is also simple.

```
create view app_view as select app_id from app_table
```

We've tried various combinations of Java applications, JDBC drivers and SQL Server.

Applications:

- Our custom Java application
- SQuirreL client (4.0.0)

JDBC drivers:

- sqljdbc4
- sqljdbc_8.2.0.jre

SQL Server versions:

- SQL Server 2017
- SQL Server 2019

Java version: 8_241

## EDIT: SQL Profiler results

I'm not sure the best way to report SQL profiling results, so I'll just summarize what SQL Profiler reports. The SSMS client executes the view query in 23 seconds. The JDBC client took over 100 seconds before the query was cancelled prior to completion.

### For the SSMS client

**SQL:BatchStarting** "select * from app_view where ..." 2020-02-26 20:04:22
< bunch of repeating stuff >
Audit Login/Logout
RPC:Completed "exec sp_reset_connection"
BatchStarting/Completed "SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ..."
< / end bunch of repeating stuff > 
**SQL:BatchCompleted "select * from app_view where ..." 2020-02-26 20:04:45

### For the JDBC client (SQuirreL)

**SQL:BatchStarting** "select * from app_view where ..." 2020-02-26 19:55:39
< bunch of repeating stuff >
Audit Login/Logout
RPC:Completed "exec sp_reset_connection"
BatchStarting/Completed "SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ..."
< / end bunch of repeating stuff >
*Query cancelled at 19:57:26*

## EDIT 2: More SQL Profiler results

I profiled the simpler query, "select top 5000 a.app_id from app_table a" in both SSMS and the JDBC client. Surprisingly, both executed quickly, in less than 1 second.

### For the SSMS client

**SQL:BatchStarting** "top 5000 a.app_id from app_table a" 2020-02-27 10:27:55.740
**SQL:BatchCompleted** "top 5000 a.app_id from app_table a" 2020-02-27 10:27:55.810

### For the JDBC client (SQuirreL)

**SQL:BatchStarting** "top 5000 a.app_id from app_table a" 2020-02-27 10:25:45.063
**SQL:BatchCompleted** "top 5000 a.app_id from app_table a" 2020-02-27 10:25:45.843

Comment: Do you really want to know "Have other developers seen similar performance issues in a Hyper-V virtual machine?" Surely you are actually only interested in how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

First, let's see if the problem is actually SQL Server, the application, or other. 
Open up SQL Profiler and start a trace.

With the trace running, execute these queries:

- `SELECT TOP 5000 a.app_id FROM dbo.app_table a;` (run this one SSMS)
- `SELECT TOP 5000 a.app_id FROM dbo.app_table a;` (run this one in your app/JDBC client)

(To be thorough, you can repeat the `SELECT` statements above against your view.)

Stop the trace and note the execution time (duration) from the respective applications.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've edited my question to include some SQL Profiler results.

Comment: Posted more SQL Profiler results for the simpler "TOP 5000" query suggested by Shane.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so we're getting somewhere with these results.

**Edit:**

The short answer to the question: the client shouldn't matter *that much* (i.e.: there shouldn't be that big of a discrepancy between SSMS vs. .Net vs. JDBC, etc.) As far as Hyper-V vs. bare-metal, bare-metal wins (assuming your disks are virtualized), for obvious reasons. You can run some I/O tests to prove this using DiskSpd (https://aka.ms/diskspd) in the VM vs. a similarly spec'd bare-metal environment.

**However** - I'm not convinced either of these factors are the problem, yet. Based on your trace results, BOTH clients performed well against the base table. Both clients performed relatively poorly against the view (the Java client worse than SSMS). So, I would still recommend, at least:

1. Refresh the view (as mentioned earlier)
2. Try a simple SELECT TOP 5000 * FROM dbo.app_view (from both clients) - without any WHERE clause - compare results.
3. Check the index fragmentation on the underlying table in SSMS (right-click the indexes "folder" under the table, click "Rebuild All", look at the numbers in the dialog.) Even PK indexes can become fragmented, which can cause performance to become erratic.
4. Try a different version of the original query, e.g.:

   SELECT *
   FROM dbo.app_view 
   where app_id % 1000 = 0

(without the SELECT ...WHERE IN ... )

Lastly, how many columns are in the output of the actual view? (If the view is quite wide, it can negatively affect the client performance due to amount of network traffic as well as client-side rendering of the data.)

Comment: Shane -- The table already had a primary key on app_id, but I did not show it in the DDL. I understand that tables need primary keys and that indices can improve performance. Restated somewhat differently, my original question is why does performance depend on what client executes against the database, and why does this client dependency show up in in a Hyper-V environment, but not with a bare-metal installation? -- Rick

Comment: Rick - I updated the answer, since the comments box is somewhat limited in character space.

Comment: Shane -- Because of deadlines, my colleagues and I have decided to go with a bare metal installation instead of one on Hyper-V. We plan to resume work on a Hyper-V installation in the summer of 2020. Thanks for your suggestions so far. I'll update you when we resume work on Hyper-V. -- Rick

Comment: Understood, sir. Best of luck with the project.